# Azure Service Bus: ReceiveMessagesAsync returns only a subset

Tags: c#, .net, azure, async-await, azureservicebus

I wrote a code to read 1000 messages one shot from an Azure Service Bus queue. I read the messages with the line: `await receiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(1000);` but only a subset of the messages are received.

I took the code from the sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/tests/Samples/Sample01_HelloWorld.cs, the SendAndReceiveMessageSafeBatch() method

This is my code:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SendAndReceiveMessage().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public static async Task SendAndReceiveMessage()
    {
        var connectionString = "myconnectionstring";
        var queueName = "myqueue";

        // since ServiceBusClient implements IAsyncDisposable we create it with "await using"
        await using var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

        // create the sender
        var sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);

        IList<ServiceBusMessage> messages = new List<ServiceBusMessage>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            messages.Add(new ServiceBusMessage($"Message {i}"));
        }

        // send the messages
        await sender.SendMessagesAsync(messages);

        // create a receiver that we can use to receive the messages
        var options = new ServiceBusReceiverOptions()
        {
            ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete
        };

        ServiceBusReceiver receiver = client.CreateReceiver(queueName, options);

        // the received message is a different type as it contains some service set properties
        IReadOnlyList<ServiceBusReceivedMessage> receivedMessages = await receiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(1000);

        Console.WriteLine($"Received {receivedMessages.Count} from the queue {queueName}");

        foreach (ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedMessage in receivedMessages)
        {
            var body = receivedMessage.Body.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(body);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("END");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestion how to read all 1000 messages one shot?

Comment: You're sending 1000 messages and then immediately trying to receive them all. Are you sure all the messages have been persisted? If you add a delay between sending and receiving, does that change the number of messages received?

Comment: Also, what is your prefetch count at?  Note that this is not a "messageCount" argument, it is specifically limiting the *maximum* number of messages that can be received at one time.

Comment: 1) You are sending messages asynchronously. All messages might not have been processed by the time you immediately call ReceiveMessagesAsync. 2) The parameter 1000 means the maximum number of messages to be returned. 3) Due to service limits, HTTP data payload limits, etc. fewer messages can be returned than requested. Call the ReceiveMessagesAsync again after a suitable delay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behaviour with Azure Service Bus. The number of messages to receive, [`maxMessages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceiver.receivemessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet) is a maximum number that is not guaranteed.

Comment: Is there a way to increase the amount of received messages?

Comment: You'll not get more than `maxMessages`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant to ask: can you influence the amount of messages returned? For example; `maxMessages` is set to 1000 but I only get 3 messages each time while there are thousands on the queue. Do I need to scale my service bus? Or is there another way to get more messages every call? Or is it; the framework decides and you have no influence?

Comment: The service sends what it can at that moment _up-to_ `maxMessages`. No way to force it to send exactly that number.